# XSD to JAXB to JPA mapping

Tags: jpa, jaxb, eclipselink

I have a fixed set of non-trivial XSDs to begin with - I can't change those but they get minor changes from time to time. These are used to generate JAXB2 classes on my side without a problem. I would need to persist a lot of properties of those Java classes to an RDBMS where I can design the schema but they'd need to be optimal, so I can't follow the original structures, should flatten deeply nested ones, etc.

I thought of using Eclipselink JPA (I can use its extensions, I'm not aiming for compatibility here) and defining all mappings via the orm.xml file - this way I wouldn't have to touch the automatically generated JAXB classes. Building the solution on heavy use of the embeddable-embedded concept could help flattening the XML structures and achieving a nice DB schema.

I'm not sure how to handle a few special cases though, like:

1. deeply nested objects which should get mapped as @Embedded in JPA but are also polymorphic (are abstract and have many possible child classes)
2. JAXBElement wrapper types
3. Maps of which only certain keys should get mapped to the DB
4. XMLGregorianCalendar-s
5. etc.

Eg. for approaching 3) I created a custom child class of the generated JAXB instance and mapped it as an entity instead of the original. The child class introduced fake getters and setters which worked on the backing Map - this works fine but feels fragile.

I'm also not sure when I'll hit the first corner case which can not really get solved with Eclipselink JPA at all and which would force me to drop the whole approach..

The question: could Eclipselink JPA be a viable approach for mapping between certain properties of existing complex JAXB types and ideally designed RDBMS schemas? If it's so, how could I handle the special cases above? If it's not, how else could I approach the problem instead?

Comment: Have you seen [Hyperjaxb](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Home)? (Disclaimer: I'm the author.)

Comment: I saw it got mentioned in some threads but wasn't sure if it's still an active project or a cancelled one. What's it's current state?

Comment: Passive, but not cancelled. https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Eclipselink](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) is a viable approach for mapping between certain properties of existing complex JAXB types and ideally designed RDBMS schemas.

> To [demonstrate](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/tree/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial#readme), the [HiSrc HyperJAXB Maven Plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb#readme) can be used to read sample XML Schema (xsd) file(s) and XML Schema Binding (xjb) file(s) to generate Java Entity classes with JPA and JAXB annotations. **Note:** The source/target (release) compatibility for *HyperJAXB* is at Java 11, up from Java 8. And, JDK 17 is used for the build. JAXB dependencies are at version 4.x for [Jakarta EE 10](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-binding/). JPA dependencies are at 2.1.

**Special cases** are handled using XML *appinfo* annotations in the XSD file(s) *and/or* schema bindings in the XJB file(s). The JAXB XJC compiler accepts plugins to customize how it generates the entities and these plugins provide XML namespaces for use in your XSD and XJB file(s). Here is a list of typical XJC plugins:

- `xmlns:annox="http://jvnet.org/basicjaxb/xjc/annox"`
- `xmlns:basic="http://jvnet.org/basicjaxb/xjc"`
- `xmlns:customizations="http://jvnet.org/basicjaxb/xjc/customizations"`
- `xmlns:hj="http://jvnet.org/hyperjaxb/jpa"`
- `xmlns:inheritance="http://jvnet.org/basicjaxb/xjc/inheritance"`
- `xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"`
- `xmlns:jl="http://jvnet.org/basicjaxb/xjc/annox/java.lang"`
- `xmlns:simplify="http://jvnet.org/basicjaxb/xjc/simplify"`
- `xmlns:vc="http://jvnet.org/basicjaxb/xjc/valueconstructor"`
- `xmlns:wildcard="http://jvnet.org/basicjaxb/xjc/wildcard"`

The **JPA/JAXB** classes are generated by the [*HiSrc HyperJAXB Maven Plugin*](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb#readme) in this project's [pom.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/project-pom.xml)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.patrodyne.jvnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>hisrc-hyperjaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>\${hisrc-hyperjaxb.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and are generated to:

```
target/generated-sources
├── apt
│   └── org
│       └── example
│           └── po
│               ├── Item_.java
│               ├── Items_.java
│               ├── PurchaseOrder_.java
│               └── USAddress_.java
└── xjc
    ├── META-INF
    │   ├── persistence.xml
    │   └── sun-jaxb.episode
    └── org
        └── example
            └── po
                ├── Item.java
                ├── Items.java
                ├── ObjectFactory.java
                ├── package-info.java
                ├── PurchaseOrder.java
                └── USAddress.java

target/test-database-sql
├── ddl-create.sql
└── ddl-drop.sql
```

[Here (zip)](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/releases/download/2.1.0/hisrc-hyperjaxb-ejb-sample-po-initial-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip) is a Maven project named **po-initial** with the standard layout. This project includes:

- The Maven POM file with `hisrc-hyperjaxb-maven-plugin`
- A [Main](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/src/main/java/org/example/po/Main.java) class to demonstrate a simple use case.
- Resources

  - [jvmsystem.properties](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/src/main/resources/jvmsystem.properties) to select an *H2* or *PostgreSQL* database.
  - [persistence*.properties](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/tree/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/src/main/resources) to configure the `EntityManagerFactory`.
  - [META-INF/orm.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/src/main/resources/META-INF/orm.xml) to configure the database schema name.
  - An XML Schema file [PurchaseOrder.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/src/main/resources/PurchaseOrder.xsd) for the `PurchaseOrder` model
  - A JAXB *binding* file [PurchaseOrder.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/src/main/resources/PurchaseOrder.xjb) for configuration
- A JUnit test class [RoundtripTest.java](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/src/test/java/org/example/po/RoundtripTest.java) to verify unmarshalling, persistence and marshaling.
- Sample XML [file(s)](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/tree/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/src/test/samples) with `purchaseOrder` data.

```
hisrc-hyperjaxb-ejb-sample-po-initial-2.1.0
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── org
    │   │       └── example
    │   │           └── po
    │   │               ├── Context.java
    │   │               └── Main.java
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── jvmsystem.arguments
    │       ├── jvmsystem.properties
    │       ├── META-INF
    │       │   └── orm.xml
    │       ├── persistence-h2.properties
    │       ├── persistence-pg.properties
    │       ├── persistence.properties
    │       ├── PurchaseOrder.xjb
    │       ├── PurchaseOrder.xsd
    │       └── simplelogger.properties
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── org
        │       └── example
        │           └── po
        │               └── RoundtripTest.java
        ├── resources
        │   ├── persistence-pg-create-database.sql
        │   └── persistence-pg-recreate-schema.sql
        └── samples
            └── po.xml
```

##### Execution

This is a stand-alone Maven project. You can run the test and/or application using either of two JPA providers:

**[Eclipselink](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)**

```
mvn -Peclipselink clean test
mvn -Peclipselink clean compile exec:java
```

or

**[Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/orm/)**

```
mvn -Phibernate clean test
mvn -Phibernate clean compile exec:java
```

This [output](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/OUTPUT.txt) shows the test results using *Eclipselink*.

###### Persistence: H2 or PostgreSQL

By default, this project uses a local [H2](https://www.h2database.com/) database. The H2 database is automatically created when the application creates its `EntityManagerFactory`.

Alternatively, this project can be re-configured to use your own [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database server.

###### Approach

The [hisrc-hyperjaxb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb#readme) is configured to generate **JPA/JAXB** classes using the provided [PurchaseOrder.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/src/main/resources/PurchaseOrder.xsd) schema. The schema provides the namespace `"http://org.example/po"` which **JAXB** uses to create the Java `package` name using its own naming convention.

As the default option, a more advanced implementation of Java's built-in `Object` methods are generated using these **XJC** [hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme). In particular, the sample project uses the `toString` plugin to display *human-readable* representations of the unmarshaled `PurchaseOrder` objects.

> *Note:* The [hisrc-hyperjaxb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb#readme) extends the [hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme) but *pre-configures* several of the **XJC** [hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme); thus, the [hisrc-basicjaxb-runtime](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme) dependency is required on the run-time class path. For more help on the configuration details, see ...

```
mvn hisrc-hyperjaxb:help -Ddetail=true
```

###### Testing

The JUnit test class, [RoundtripTest.java](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/src/test/java/org/example/po/RoundtripTest.java), scans for the sample files and invokes the method `super.checkSample(File sample)` to provide each file to the tester. For this project, an `EntityManagerFactory` and a `JAXBContext` are created and each file in the [samples](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/tree/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/src/test/samples) path is:

- *unmarshaled* to an initial `PurchaseOrder` object
- *unmarshaled* to an etalon `PurchaseOrder` object
- A JPA transaction is started.

  - The initial object is *merged* into the persistence session
- The JPA transaction is committed
- A new JPA `EntityManager`, *em*, instance is created

  - The new *em* is used to load the persisted PO by id
  - The etalon, merged and loaded PO objects are compared for equality
- The *em* is closed and each PO object is marshaled for review in the logs

When successful, each object is *marshaled* for logging and your [review](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/OUTPUT.txt).

###### Demonstration

A Java standard engine application with a `main(...)` method is at [`org.example.po.Main`](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial/src/main/java/org/example/po/Main.java). This application is executed using:

```
mvn -Peclipselink clean compile exec:java -Dexec.args="src/test/samples/po.xml"
OR
mvn -Phibernate   clean compile exec:java -Dexec.args="src/test/samples/po.xml"
```

*Disclaimer:* I am the maintainer of the forked HiSrc projects.